# Profile using eBPF inside kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ebpf

I am trying to profile a kubernetes pod using the BCC tools. The environment is:

- minikube v1.8.0
- installed linux kernel headers installed on the host by following the steps: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/ebpf_tools_in_minikube/
- Spin up zlim/bcc container inside the cluster, verified that execsnoop works.

When I run "profile" inside the container, I see the BCC is working to get profile output.

However, if I run "profile -p " using a pid of a container, the profile output comes out empty.

There are 2 ways I get the pid of a container:

1. "docker ps" followed by "docker inspect <container_id> '{{ .State.Pid }}'"
2. Directly check "ps" on the minikube console.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you take the PID returned by `docker inspect`, what's the output of running `ps -[that_pid]` on the host?

Comment: `$ ps -6138
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 6138 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh /sbin/boot.sh
 6400 ?        S      0:00 runsvdir -P /etc/service`

Comment: Could it be that your process running `/sbin/boot.sh` is actually calling some other process doing the actual work and not doing anything itself?